# Rails: NoMethodError, how do I show users profiles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I type at the top, `/users/1` or `/users/2` I get the same page yet there are 2 users. It just redirects me back to show.html.rb page. I'm not sure but maybe I don't have a page for each user. Maybe you can look at my code. I am unable to show `<%= @user.name %>`, I get a `NoMethodError in Users#show`. Maybe that is the problem...

**show.html.rb**

```
Avatar, <%= image_tag(current_user.avatar.url(:medium)) %>

Hello, <%= current_user.name %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

   resources :products


   get 'users/index'
   get 'users/show'

   devise_for :users do
       resources :posts 
   end

   get 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user


   resources :posts do
     member do
         get "like", to: "posts#upvote"
         get "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"


     end
     resources :comments
   end

   root 'posts#index'

end
```

I have each user in Show.html.rb and an index showing all the users at Index.html.rb

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @users = User.all
    end

    def edit
        @user = User.create( user_params )
    end

  def show
      @user = User.find_by_name(params[:id])
  end


 private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :avatar)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

users_controller.rb

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

You are trying to find user with his name and you are passing id. Change the query as above and check and you have added two routes for show method so remove first route.

Comment: Great, thank worked. How do I prevent other users from changing other users pages? `<% if current_user %>` doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

do you have show page under user.if do not means create one..i think it may be also a problem

Answer (score 1):

You have created two routes for `users/show` show page. Remove `get 'users/show'` and try again

Comment: Thanks. How do I prevent other users from changing other users pages? `<% if current_user %>` doesn't seem to work?

Comment: you can check it in controlller as,
`def show
      @user = User.find_by_name(params[:id])
       unless current_user == @user
           redirect_to root_path
       end
  end`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `current_user` in your `show` page, that is why you always get the same result every time. The route is not the problem. You should change your controller's action to:

```
def show
  @user = User.find params[:id]
end
```

And then update your view to:

```
Avatar, <%= image_tag(@user.avatar.url(:medium)) %>
Hello, <%= @user.name %>
```